# 5 px border added to button, Button size increases. Box-sizing not working

Tags: html, css

On button I am adding active class with 5px border-bottom. Button size increases by 5px. I dont want to get button size increased. Is there any simple way to do so? Box-sizing not working.

```css
*,
*:after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.button {
  background: black;
  width: 150px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button active">button active</button>
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: box-sizing not supported by button/input tags

Answer (score 4):

> With respect to `border` `box-sizing: border-box` will work if you are
>   giving a fixed height to the button element.

**Solution1 with fixed height**

```css
*,
*:after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.button {
  background: black;
  width: 150px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  height: 53px;
}

.button.active {
  border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button active">button active</button>
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>
```

**Solution2 without fixed height(Using :before css pseudo selector)**

```css
*,
*:after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.button {
  background: black;
  width: 150px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.button.active:before {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button active">button active</button>
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: But the issue isn't with  border that is increasing the size, he's using box-sizing:bored-box and border is included in the box-model. The issue is that he reached the min-height so that the inner height can no more be reduced ... if there was enough height, adding border won't affect total height.

Comment: @TemaniAfif with respect to `border` `box-sizing: border-box` will work if you are giving a fixed height to the button, but in this case the height is no fix.

Comment: yes i totaly agree and since we didn't specify a height, the element is getting the content height (the min-height) and then it can no more be decreased ;) ... and am sure that's why the OP said `box-sizing is not working`. so if we add the explanation about the height then he will understand :)

Answer (score 3):

So, Here is why box-sizing wont solve your problem.
You command css to add 20px of padding for both buttons and css obey! then you command css to add 5px of border to the active button and again css obey! then you want both button to be equal ? do you meant to reduce padding of the first one! because it is the only way to make them equal . here is a how:

```
.active {
  border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
  padding:calc(20px - 5px);
}
```

i've used function calc() in case anyone is using rems or ems as unit.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** `box-shadow`

```css
*,
*:after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.button {
  background: black;
  width: 150px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 yellow inset
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button active">button active</button>
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:** pseudo-element `::after`

```css
*,
*:after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.button {
  /* Add Position Relative for Button */
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  width: 150px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.active::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button active">button active</button>
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try to add a black 5px border on the default button style, and the yellow color for the active button

```
.button {
  background: black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding you need shadow for the button.
Its better to use shadow on the button.

Use this

```
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #aaaaaa;
```

Then configure it as you want.

Answer (score -2):

Declare your button `height` inside `.active` class and `box-sizing: border-box`. You are good to go ...... :)

```css
*,
*:after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.button {
  background: black;
  width: 150px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.active {
border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button active">button active</button>
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>
```